# getting practice

Tags: sentence-construction

I tried to make a sentence:

> Through reading technical literature and getting practice of what you
>   read you will come to understand this technique in depth.

Is that sentence correct? I was not sure about `getting practice` and `come to understand` in such a context. Do the phrases sound good here?

Comment: looks fine to me

Answer (score 1):

I would say:

> Through reading technical literature and **by practicing** what you read, you will **come to understand** this technique in depth.

You don't need the *getting*, just use a form of *practice* similar to *reading*.
I wouldn't say *by* is required, but without it you are saying *through practicing* which seems odd to me.

And *come to understand* is fine.

Comment: "through. . . practicing" doesn't sound odd to me.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock I meant saying "Through reading technical literature and *through* practicing what you read..." with both phrases using "through" sounded odd to me.

Comment: That's why we leave out the second "through". It's redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is correct and perfectly understandable. You could have minor "improvements" such as what the previous answer suggested. But its current form is solid.